# react:initialize value for the redux state

Tags: reactjs, redux

I amtrying to initialize a component with a default value in redux state.
Here is the code to call the root node:

```
const str="Italy quake: Norcia tremor destroys ancient buildings";
const words = str.split(" ");
const preloadedState = { randomWords: {
  activeWord:0,
  activeLetter:0,
  words:words
}};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStore(root_reducer,preloadedState)}>
      <App />
  </Provider>,document.getElementById('root')
);
```

and the combineReducers is:

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import RandomWords from './RandomWordsReducer';
import Score from './ScoreReducer';

const root_reducer=combineReducers({
    randomWords:RandomWords,
    score:Score
});


export default root_reducer;
```

and in the container, i have connected the component with redux:
(I am sure the component and the redux are connected)

```
 function mapStateToProps(state){

        return ({words:state.words,
                activeLetter:state.activeLetter,
                activeWord:state.activeWord});
    }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps)(RandomWords);
```

Then on the Component I have:

```
export default class RandomWords extends Component{

      render(){
        console.log("words are:"+this.props.words);
          return(<div>
              {  this.props.words }
            </div>)
      }
}
```

The problem is:
In the line  `console.log("words are:"+this.props.words);` **i expect to see an array of words, meanwhile it is undefined.**

What is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `state.words`, only a `state.randomWords.words`:

```
return ({words:state.randomWords.words,
        activeLetter:state.randomWords.activeLetter,
        activeWord:state.randomWords.activeWord});
```

Comment: I was looking for it - tucked that one away here `const preloadedState = { randomWords: {` and I didn't spot it.